# Finding the probability of number of edges in a graph

Tags: probability

I've got a question in probability.
We've got a graph $G=(V,E)$ where the number of vertexes is $10$. The probability that for any edge to be in $E$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

**1)** What is the probability that $G$ has exactly $15$ edges?

**2)** How many triangles (cycles with the length $3$) does $G$ have?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Erdos-Renyi graph on 10 nodes with parameter $p=1/2$. The total possible edges is $\binom{10}{2}$.

1) The presence of each edge is an independent Bernoulli(1/2) random variable. Thus, the number of edges in G follows a Binomial$(\binom{10}{2},1/2)$ distribution.

2) Presumably this is expectation. See [these notes](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/462/2007/lect11-07.pdf) on the probabilistic method.

Comment: We didn't learn binomial distribution, I think the way we have to do it is with indicators(random variable with the values {0,1}.